# How do i specify which files to remove from the .gitignore which are still visible in the repository

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I want specific files to not be visible in my github repo after adding the gitignore

I only tried deleting from my github repo but it seems like that is not the way to do it, i want them to automatically get ignored when committing to my repo.

Answer (score 0):

To untrack every file that is now in your `.gitignore` run the following command to remove everything from the index.

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Following that run `git add` to add all files, except those in `.gitignore`:

```
git add .
```

Then commit it with an appropriate message:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

And push to GitHub.

```
git push
```

> Please be careful, when you push this to a repository and pull from
> somewhere else into a state where those files are still tracked, the
> files will be DELETED